# Save button not working on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a pretty basic visualforce page on the opportunity object which is just a page displaying some fields for a user to edit. The save button doesn't seem to be working? Any ideas, ideally it would save and close the window.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Opportunity">
 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock title="Finance Checklist for Opportunities">         
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
       <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Do_all_text_fields_have_correct_spelling__c}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Are_all_the_dates_appropriate__c}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Does_the_total_value_match_the_SOAW__c}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Contains_recurring_products__c}"/>
   <br></br>
   <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Recurring_information_correct__c}"/>
   <br></br>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{! save}" value="Save!"/>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Add a `<apex:pageMessages />` to your page. The save may be failing because of some validation error and that tag will display such error messages.

Comment: ahh that's great, I've done that and it looks like its actually not recognising that those fields are associated with the opportunity at all! I guess that an error with my custom link

Answer (score -2):

you have a space between the exclamation and the word save which is causing an issue:

```
action="{! save}"
```

Try doing

```
action="{!save}"
```